# Discord.py close Bot from background thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, discord, python-asyncio

I don't really have a good reason for this but stuck to my head and I now really want to do this. I have a discord bot for my discord server that is mostly used at the evening. So I wanted to make a thread that closes the bot during its "inactive" hours. However, I'm really struggling to make it. What I have so far:

```py
async def wait():
    print('In thread')
    time.sleep(5)
    await bot.close()
    print('Bot should now be stopped')


def threat():
    asyncio.run(wait())

p1 = Process(target=threat)
p1.start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

That's not all of the code, but these are the important stuff. Generally, I don't really understand what all the fuss with asyncio, since either way you have to wait for one coroutine to finish in order to get to the next one, all the while it is blocking your execution.. Isn't that plain ol' linear execution then?

Anyway, any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do with task

```
...
from discord.ext import tasks

...

@task.loop(seconds=3600) # this will execute the func. every 1 hour
async def Do_Something():
    # your code 
...
```

for more you can read the official documentation.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

Comment: I added this:
```python
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def death():
    await bot.close()
    print("I died?")
```
But nothing happens. In the docs I see they use the Cog class, do I have to add this in such a class?

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment so I add a new one..
I wasn't calling the .start() method to start the task. I added it in a Cog class and works perfectly fine. Also it is `@task**s**.loop` not `@task.loop`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just basically use the time module and make a function that checks the hour every 30 minutes for example or when a command is executed (if your bot has commands).
Then if the returned hour is in your "inactive" timestamp just close the bot.